# Frage über die richtige Reihenfolge von Satzgliedern

Tags: sentence-structure

Ein Fehler, den ich oft begehe, ist der der falschen Reihenfolge der Satzteile. In einer Aufgabe habe ich  Z.B, das Folgendes geschrieben

> Sofort verliebt er sich in sie und hofft, dass sie ihn auch liebt.

während die richtige Antwort heißt

> ...und hofft, dass auch sie ihn liebt.

Meines Erachtens sollte man die Pronomen direkt nach "dass" stellen. Offensichtlich nicht! Unter welcher Rubrik sollte ich weitersuchen, um dieses Thema gut zu lernen?

Comment: Es ist mir schon mehrmals aufgefallen, und da du ja deinem Deutsch den letzten Feinschliff geben willst: es heißt *Frage zu*, nicht *Frage über*.

Comment: Dein "falsches" Beispiel ist durchaus auch richtig und gängig. Dein "richtiges" ist ein bisschen gehobener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wer hat das so korrigiert? Den ersten Satz finde ich als Muttersprachler viel natürlicher als den zweiten Satz. "Auch" verhält sich fast genau wie "nicht": Es steht normalerweise am Ende und beschreibt den ganzen Satz. Steht es mal nicht am Ende, so beschreibt es das folgende Satzglied oder manchmal die folgenden Satzglieder.

Daher ist

> ..., dass sie ihn auch liebt.

völlig richtig. Mehr noch: Ich dachte erst, der zweite Satz macht keinen Sinn. Denn ich habe den Satz zuerst als

> ..., dass auch *sie* ihn liebt.

gelesen. *kursiv* steht für Betonung. Ist nur das "sie" betont, so beschreibt "auch" nur "sie". Der Rest des Satzes müsste gleich bleiben. Der Satz setzt also voraus, dass jemand anderes ihn liebt, so wie z.B.

> Ich liebe ihn und hoffe, dass auch *sie* ihn liebt.

Das ist hier aber nicht der Fall (er liebt sie). Aber ich hatte schon erwähnt, dass "auch" auch mehrere Satzglieder beschreiben kann. Betont man sowohl "sie" als auch "ihn"

> ..., dass auch *sie* (Pause) *ihn* liebt.

Dann macht der Satz Sinn: Irgendjemand liebt irgendjemanden, und auch sie ihn. Diese doppelte Betonung ist aber eher ungewöhnlich. Daher finde ich deine Variante mit

> ..., dass sie ihn auch liebt.

immer noch am besten.

Comment: Danke.  Niemand hat den Satz korrigiert, sondern er kam aus einer Übung aus dem Buch "Deutsch - Übungsgrammatik für die Oberstufe aktuell".  Mann musste den hergehobenen Satzteil aus "Sofort verliebt er sich in sie und hofft *auf ihre Gebenliebe*" in Infinitivsatz oder Nebensatz mit "dass" umformen  Ich schrieb meine Antwort (oben), aber die Antwort bei den Lösungen war anders.

Answer (score 0):

### Reihenfolge der Satzglieder:

**Grundregel:** Subjekt - Prädikat - Objekt - Adverbialsatz

**Beispiele:**

- Der Junge kickt den Ball.
- Gestern hat der Bruder Kuchen gebacken.

**Abweichungen:** Nebensatz am Anfang, Subjekt am Ende.

**Details:**

- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satzglied
- https://studyflix.de/deutsch/satzglieder-bestimmen-3797
- https://www.kapiert.de/satzglieder-die-stellung-im-satz/

Comment: Ich habe den Beispielsatz verbessert.

Comment: Diese "Grundregel" existiert nicht: das Verb (genauer: dessen flektierter Teil) muß im Aussagesatz immer an zweiter Stelle stehen, ansonsten ist die Anordnung der Satzglieder hauptsächlich eine Frage der Betonung.